# graphql product query huge perfomance hit when filtering with multiple attributes

Tags: product-list, magento2.3.2, graphql

I have used the below GRAPHQL query to get the product list.

```
{
  products(filter: {category_id: {eq: "77"},color:{in:["5437","5438","5449"]}, price:{from:"100", to:"200"},paint_usability:{in:["5554"]},paint_quantity:{in:["5553","5546"]}, approval:{in:["2", "4"]}}, pageSize: 10, sort: {name: DESC}) {
}
```

but It will take time to get the product data. I have enabled SQL log and I find one query to load the time

```
INSERT INTO `search_tmp_60a797f2ed7ce8_60598401` SELECT `main_select`.`entity_id`, SUM(score) AS `relevance` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  `search_index`.`entity_id`, (((0) + (0) + (0) + (0) + (0) + (0) + (0)) * 1) AS `score` FROM `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `search_index`
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_index` ON stock_index.product_id = search_index.entity_id AND `stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `color_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `color_filter`.`entity_id` AND `color_filter`.`attribute_id` = 93 AND `color_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `approval_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `approval_filter`.`entity_id` AND `approval_filter`.`attribute_id` = 165 AND `approval_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `paint_quantity_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `paint_quantity_filter`.`entity_id` AND `paint_quantity_filter`.`attribute_id` = 197 AND `paint_quantity_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `paint_usability_filter` ON `search_index`.`entity_id` = `paint_usability_filter`.`entity_id` AND `paint_usability_filter`.`attribute_id` = 198 AND `paint_usability_filter`.`store_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `color_filter_stock_index` ON color_filter_stock_index.product_id = color_filter.source_id AND `color_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `color_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `approval_filter_stock_index` ON approval_filter_stock_index.product_id = approval_filter.source_id AND `approval_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `approval_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `paint_quantity_filter_stock_index` ON paint_quantity_filter_stock_index.product_id = paint_quantity_filter.source_id AND `paint_quantity_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `paint_quantity_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `paint_usability_filter_stock_index` ON paint_usability_filter_stock_index.product_id = paint_usability_filter.source_id AND `paint_usability_filter_stock_index`.`website_id` = 0 AND `paint_usability_filter_stock_index`.`stock_id` = 1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_eav` AS `visibility_filter` ON search_index.entity_id = visibility_filter.entity_id AND `visibility_filter`.`attribute_id` = 99 AND `visibility_filter`.`value` in ('2', '4') AND `visibility_filter`.`store_id` = '1'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `category_ids_index` ON search_index.entity_id = category_ids_index.product_id AND category_ids_index.store_id = '1'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON search_index.entity_id = price_index.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' WHERE (search_index.store_id = '1') AND (category_ids_index.category_id in ('77')) AND (`price_index`.`min_price` >= '100' AND `price_index`.`min_price` <= '200' AND `price_index`.`customer_group_id` = 0) AND (color_filter.value  IN ('5437','5438','5449')) AND (approval_filter.value  IN ('2','4')) AND (paint_quantity_filter.value  IN ('5553','5546')) AND (paint_usability_filter.value  IN ('5554'))) AS `main_select` GROUP BY `entity_id` ORDER BY `relevance` DESC, `entity_id` DESC
 LIMIT 9223372036854775807
```

any solution on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling elastic search my issue got resolved. my product data loaded within **`600MS`**.